# Reading XML with .ajax

Tags: javascript, xml

I wrote the following code to read a variable from an XML file. The variable is not being passed to the Highchart graph, and I'm not sure why.  The graph works correctly when I insert numbers in place of the variables.

```html
    <script>

    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "data.xml",
       dataType: "xml",
       success: function(xml) {
         $(xml).find('height').each(function(){
           var johnheight = $(this).find('john').text()
           var mikeheight = $(this).find('mike').text()
         });
       }
    });
    
    $(function () { 
    var myChart = Highcharts.chart('graph', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        xAxis: {
        categories: [''],
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [johnheight]
        }, {
            name: 'Mike',
            data: [mikeheight]
        }]
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(function() {})` does not await `$.ajax()` call and the variables are defined only within `.each()`. You can use `$.holdReady()` to await `$.ajax()` `success` function and declare variables before function calls, optionally on the `window` or other object, and define the variables within `.each()`

```
$.holdReady(true);

var johnheight = mikeheight = void 0;

$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "data.xml",
       dataType: "xml",
       success: function(xml) {
         $(xml).find('height').each(function(){
           johnheight = $(this).find('john').text();
           mikeheight = $(this).find('mike').text();
           return false;
         });
         $.holdReady(false);
       }
    });

$(function () { 
    var myChart = Highcharts.chart('graph', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        xAxis: {
        categories: [''],
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [johnheight]
        }, {
            name: 'Mike',
            data: [mikeheight]
        }]
    });
    });
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense now that I know about the $.holdReady method.  However, I believe I have a mistake elsewhere in my code since the variable is still not being passed to the chart.  In fact, the chart doesn't load at all based on my .ajax code.

Comment: Is `Highcharts` defined? Are there any errors logged at `console`?

Comment: Yes, Highcharts works fine without the .ajax code. It's looking for ajaxgetdata.js which it cannot find.  I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: What is `ajaxgetdata.js`?

Comment: I'm not sure.  That's the error from the console.  It just said it failed to load a resource, and then gives a URL pointing to that file.  It is graphing now, but is not pulling the values from the XML file.

Comment: Found it, it was left over elsewhere on the site.  Now I just need to figure out why it isn't pulling the value from the XML file.

Comment: Why is `.each()` necessary? Can you include XML at Question?

Comment: In case there are more than one XML parents named "height".  Is there a way to make this even simpler, and just pull the value from the XML file for <mikeheight>68</mikeheight> or <johnheight>72</johnheight>?  If I limit the XML file to one parent category called "height" then this shouldn't have to iterate through the parents.